# Rails 5.1 webpack with react and displaying tasks

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am trying to get a Rails 5.1 app with webpack and react installed to display tasks from the TasksController. Here are the relavant files:

## index.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'tasks_container', {tasks: @tasks} %>
```

## app/javascript/packs/tasks_container.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

var TasksContainer = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            tasks: this.props.tasks
        }
    },

  renderTaskRows: function(){
      return(
        this.props.tasks.map(function(task){
          return(
            <div className="row" style={{marginTop: "20px"}} key={task.id}>

              <div className="col-sm-2">
                {task.name}
              </div>

              <div className="col-sm-2">
                {task.number_of_hours}
              </div>

            </div>
          )
        })
      );
    },

    render: function() {
    return(
      <div>

        <div className="row" style={{marginTop: "50px"}}>

          <div className="col-sm-2" style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>
            Name
          </div>

        </div>

        {this.renderTaskRows()}

      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

I am not getting any errors in the console. I can add a console.log message to tasks_containter.jsx (before the var TasksContainer) and I can see that in the console, so I at least know I am getting to that far. If I try and log tasks like this...

```
var TasksContainer = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            tasks: this.props.tasks
        }
    console.log(tasks)
    },
...
```

I don't get anything in the console.

Comment: What does your rails server or foreman print?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma good call...here is output: https://gist.github.com/marklocklear/bfc0dc22a88ab743d73b9a08a4fb2c09 Everything seems to be on order.